# Applying adapter to ListFragment

Tags: android

I have a simple question.
just as we are able to apply adapter to ListActivity in the following way :

```
getListView().setAdapter(new myadapter());
```

the same does not work for ListFragment.

Can anybody update why this does not work apart from quoting from the api reference.

```
public class mylistfrag extends ListFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ListView lv=getListView();
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,((myfragshow)getActivity()).st);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
    }

}

public class myfragshow extends FragmentActivity
{
String st[]={"a","b","C","d","e"};
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.myfragshow);
    }
}
```

[image]

thanks

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description. You have to specify `android:id="@android:id/list"` for the `ListView` in your `Fragment`'s layout and access it in `onCreateView()`

Comment: @blackbelt  I am doing this in onActivityCreated method

Comment: should also work fine. Do you have the mentioned id?

Comment: @Droidman The list does not show any data .It keeps on loading .I am using getListView() to get the ListView object and attaching adapter to it.

Comment: well I guess your `ListView` is not null since you'd get an `NPE`. If no data is shown I see 2 possible reasons: your `Adapter` is empty or your `Fragment` is not visible. Try logging `getCount()` in your `Adapter` and `yourFrag.isAdded()` `yourFrag.isVisible()` in your `Activity` hosting this `Fragment`

Comment: @Droidman the id is not required to be mentioned in case we extend from ListFragment as no layout is required in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

**problem:**

```
getListView()
```

when you are trying to call that method within your fragment it will call your activity's listview reference not your fragment's listview

here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#getListView()):

```
Get the activity's list view widget.
```

instead directly use the `setListAdapter` to set the adapter of the fragment

**sample:**

```
setListAdapter((new myadapter()));
```

Comment: hmm, I just checked a recent project of mine where I use a `ListFragment` (`lv` is a class field). `lv = getListView(); lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);` works fine called in `onActivityCreated()`

Comment: I would guess there's a typo in the docs, some kinda copy-paste mistake from `ListActivity` documentation

Comment: @Droidman it is not working . i have attached the screen shot in the original post.the code of onActivityCreated is also added.

Comment: @user2779311 show all the code in your myfragshow class

Answer (score 0):

for a ListFragment you have to use ListFragment.setListAdapter() as if you use setadapter important initialization will be skipped.